# Correlating bitmap size to window units at 96DPI

Tags: visual-studio, bitmap, mfc, dpi

I am creating bitmaps for my MFC application.  My desktop is set at 96dpi, and i am trying to fill a 29x25 bitmap button. Our example bitmaps that we are using are sized at 42x40.  When overlayed onto our buttons, the images don't look nearly as clear and crisp as i would expect.

Just as an example, here is the code that i am using:

```
CBitmapButton::DrawItem(lpDIS);

CDC *dcMem, *pdcBmp;
// Get the DC for the Base Bitmap
dcMem = CDC::FromHandle(lpDIS->hDC);
pdcBmp = new CDC();
pdcBmp->CreateCompatibleDC(dcMem);
DrawOverlay(&selectedBmp, pdcBmp, dcMem);  //selected bmp is a class variable

void OverlayButton::DrawOverlay(CBitmap *bmp, CDC *pdcBmp, CDC *dcMem)
{
    BITMAP bitmapInfo;
    bmp->GetBitmap(&bitmapInfo);
    pdcBmp->SelectObject(bmp);
    dcMem->TransparentBlt(0, 0, bitmapInfo.bmWidth, bitmapInfo.bmHeight,
    pdcBmp, 0, 0, bitmapInfo.bmWidth, bitmapInfo.bmHeight,
    RGB(192, 192, 192));
}
```

So my questions are these:
How do i go about determining the correct size for a bitmap or button to fit the bitmap without stretching and potentially losing detail?

if i had a 32x32 bitmap, how would that correspond to window units in VS with the the 96dpi?

Comment: Where are you currently stuck?   What solved this for you?

Answer (score 0):

DPI is dots per inch.  Each dot is a pixel.   It simply allows you to know how many pixels per inch you can see.   So you 32x32 bit map will be 1/3 of an inch by 1/3 of an inch on your screen.  That isn't really relevant for your problem.

*"I am trying to fill a 29x25 bitmap button. Our example bitmaps that we are using are sized at 42x40."*

That's the source of your problem.  If you have a 29x25 pixel button with a bitmap image on it, use a 29x25 pixel bitmap for that image.   Using a 42x40 one isn't even the right aspect ratio.   I'm not at all surprised it appears distorted.

Your best bet is to match the pixel size exactly or to have a power of 2 more.   So, 58x50 or 116x100, but 29x25 will give you exactly what you want.

It make it fit the button, set the destination to the button's width and height.   But, it sounds like you already made the button the right size.   I'm just curious how you set the size.   Did you use code to set the pixel size, or did you use some other 'size' from a GUI?

```
dcMem->TransparentBlt(0, 0, button.width, button.height, pdcBmp, 0, 0, bitmapInfo.bmWidth, bitmapInfo.bmHeight, ...
```

Comment: That makes sense.  In this case, does using a larger, properly scaled bitmap give me greater detail? or does it get lost when squeezing it down to the destination size?

Comment: When you use a larger image, it gets scaled by the built in functions.   You are better off providing exactly the image you want to be displayed.   Some images, when scaled down, acquire odd artifacts.   Its easiest to simply use the image size you want.   However, if your GUI design is in flux and unstable and button sizes are subject to change, it can get annoying to have to regenerate the images every time.

Comment: i quickly modified my sample program to use a button that was 42x40 units to match the icon that is also 42x40 pixels.  What i am seeing that the image makes no attempt to actually fill the size of the button. The button size is in visual studio, so i was under the impression that a 42x40 button in VS, doesn't not equal 42x40 pixels, but rather some amount of scaling was involved.

Comment: Thats more of a dock/anchor problem.   Just getting your forms setup correctly for what you desire.    That I don't understand the question exactly.   Screen shots of what you mean by the two sizes might assist me (or someone else) to understand exactly the problem so we can get you right solution.

Comment: It's not a dock/anchor issue.  In my example code, i was calling transparentblt and passing in the bitmap size to both the source and destination sizes.  This shows that there is not a 1:1 correlation from dialog unit to pixel size.  I updated the code to properly pass in the size of the button as the destination size, but it still doesn't resolve the question of how to size my bitmap button to properly fit the existing bitmap without having to stretch/shrink.

Comment: In the code above (TransparentBlt), you draw the bitmap in as the size of the bitmap.  Which, if the button is exactly the same size, should fill it.   I don't see anything in the code example or debug output that shows the button sizes or bitmap sizes.

Comment: for the button sized as 29wx25h in visual studio, the actual size ends up being 41w x 44h.  the bitmap was sized at 42wx40h.  My point is that without looking to the code after GetwindowRect() and ScreenToClient, i would never know what size to make a button that would fit the bitmap without having to stretch it in some way.

Comment: Still don't know what you mean 'in visual studio' vs 'actual size'?   Is there some way to get actual size without using visual studio?   Are you just hitting print screen and counting pixels?

Comment: when i create a control in VS, it has the height and width in dialog units down at the bottom.  In my case, i'm setting to 29x25.  If i break in my code where i am overlaying my bitmap onto that control, i can see that the control is actually 41wx44h pixels.  that shows that there is not a 1:1 correlation between the size i set a control at design time, and the number of pixels.  
I use GetWindowRect(), then call ScreenToClient().  i break and look at the height/width.

Comment: I see.   Are the changes because of the margin settings?   Perhaps you have 6 pixels of width margin set and such?    Perhaps you have the AutoSize property set to true?   Some screen shots of the properties and such would go a long way towards making this solvable.   When I create a button in the form and set the width to 203 and then examine the button->Size.Width in a click callback(or wherever) its still 203.